# Why is it important for functions to be anonymous in lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

I was watching the lecture by Jim Weirich, titled '[Adventures in Functional Programming](http://vimeo.com/45140590)'. In this lecture, he introduces the concept of Y-combinators, which essentially finds the fixed point for higher order functions.

One of the motivations, as he mentions it, is to be able to express recursive functions using lambda calculus so that the theory by Church (anything that is effectively computable can be computed using lambda calculus) stays.

The problem is that a function cannot call itself simply so, because lambda calculus does not allow named functions, i.e.,

$$n(x, y) = x + y$$

cannot bear the name '$n$', it must be defined anonymously:

$$(x, y) \rightarrow x + y $$

Why is it important for lambda calculus to have functions that are not named? What principle is violated if there are named functions? Or is it that I just misunderstood jim's video?

Comment: This doesn't sound important at all. You can assign $(x,t) \mapsto x+y$ to a variable $n$ and then you have given a name to the function.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, you can bind a name to a function. I think the real question here, the puzzlement, is why (in lambda calculus) can't a function call itself by such a name? Why do we need a technique like the Y operator in order to do recursive functions? I hope my answer below helps.

Comment: @Jerry101 The historical reason for the absence of self-application is that $\lambda$-calculus was intended to be a foundation of mathematics, and the ability to self-apply makes such a foundation immediately inconsistent. So this apparent inability (which we know now can be circumvented) is a design feature of $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: @MartinBerger please say more. Inconsistent for the reason in my answer? Or for another reason?

Comment: @Jerry101 Inconsistent in the sense that you can prove 0 = 1 in such a foundation of mathematics.  After Kleene and Rosser showed the inconsistency of the pure, untyped $\lambda$-calculus, the simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus was developed as an alternative that does not allow us to define fix-point combintors such as $Y$. But if you add recursion to the simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus it again becomes inconsistent, because every type is inhabited by a non-terminating program.

Comment: Thank you, @MartinBerger! So λ-calculus as a basis for mathematics (or at least deductive logic) avoided self-reference in an unsuccessful attempt to rule out Curry's paradox. I'll amend my answer. Feel free to take crack at explaining it better.

Comment: @Jerry101 Yes, that's right, and because of these design choices (which failed in their original goal), we got a programming language that can do self-application only indirectly, and needs anonymous functions for recursion (or alternatively needs additional constructs such as explicit recursion, or a mechanism for fresh name generation).

Comment: @MartinBerger Yes, and we're getting yet more programming languages with static type systems that are complicated, distracting, in the way of desirable programs, and still can't fulfill their goals.

Comment: @Jerry101 I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @MartinBerger Like type systems intended to prevent Russell's or Curry's paradox, programming language designers use elaborate static type systems to catch problems at compile time. It works to a degree but seriously gets in the way and requires loopholes to do reflection & dynamic loading. Probably a small % of Java programmers understand co/contravariance and how to write wildcards. That's a usability & engineering failure. My bet is on the approach in Strongtalk and Dart: runtime checking plus simple, optional, "unsound" static types. Cf http://onewebsql.com/blog/generics-crash , Ceylon, ..

Comment: @Jerry101  I agree that Java types have some weak spots, in particular exception specifications and its approach to parametric polymorphism. But type systems in the ML tradition are just wonderful.

Comment: @MartinBerger I'll try ML sometime but I'm skeptical, esp. after seeing Ceylon's effort to do it better than Java & ML (with scarey proposals like https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-spec/issues/899). I gave up on Haskell trying to figure out monads. Haskell hinges on monads. Reading a monad tutorial in Haskell, most of the brain power goes into constructing hypotheses about Haskell: precedence, parametric polymorphism (how does it know which "return" to call?), misleading terminology ("return"?), type classes, ... It turns out monads are not difficult when explained in JavaScript.

Comment: @Jerry101 Monads are simple, but the concept takes a couple of attempts to assimilate. That's not Haskells' fault. Anyway, we are veering far away from the original question.

Comment: isnt YFs comment a typo, did he mean $(x,y)$ not $(x,t)$?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The main theorem regarding this issue is due to a British mathematician from
the end of the 16th century, called [William Shakespeare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare). His best known
paper on the subject is entitled "[Romeo and Juliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_and_Juliet)" was published in
1597, though the research work was conducted a few years earlier,
inspired but such precursors as Arthur Brooke and William Painter.

His main result, stated in [Act II. Scene II](http://www.bartleby.com/70/3822.html), is the [famous theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet):

> What's in a name? that which we call a rose
>   By any other name would smell as sweet;

This theorem can be intuively understood as "names do not contribute
to meaning".

The greater part of the paper is devoted to an example complementing
the theorem and showing that, even though names contribute no meaning,
they are the source of endless problems.

As pointed out by Shakespeare, names can be changed without changing
meaning, an operation that was later called [$\alpha$-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B1-conversion) by [Alonzo
Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church) and his followers. As a
consequence, it is not necessarily simple to determine what is denoted
by a name. This raises a variety of issues such as developing a
concept of environment where the name-meaning association are
specified, and rules to know what is the current environment when you
try to determine the meaning associated with a name. This baffled
computer scientists for a while, giving rise to technical
difficulties such as the infamous [Funarg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem). Environments remain
an issue in some popular programming languages, but it is generally
considered physically unsafe to be more specific, almost as lethal as
the example worked out by Shakespeare in his paper.

This issue is also close to the problems raised in [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) theory,
when alphabets and formal systems have to be [defined up to an
isomorphism](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14517), so as to underscore that the [symbols of the alphabets are
abstract entities](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22255), independent of how they "materialize" as elements
from some set.

This major result by Shakespeare shows also that science was then diverging
from magic and religion, where a being or a meaning may have a [true name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name).

The conclusion of all this is that for theoretical work, it is often
more convenient not to be encumbered by names, even though it may feel
simpler for practical work and everyday life. But recall that not
everyone called Mom is your mother.

**Note**:
The issue was addressed more recently by the 20th century American logician
[Gertrude Stein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gertrude_Stein). However, her mathematician colleagues are still
pondering the precise technical implications of her [main theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose):

> Rose is a rose is a rose is a rose.

published in 1913 in a short communication entitled "Sacred Emily".

Comment: Additional note: In recent decades "rose" has (in computer science) been mostly replaced by "foobar" (and parts thereof) as the canonical example for a name that is as good as any other. This preference has [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) been introduced by American railroad engineers.

Comment: That said, canonical names for often used concepts are important for efficient communication.

Comment: @Raphael Agreed, but I would put that in the everyday life category. And how do
we know the boundaries of what is really canonical? Still, I often
feel concern when I see students taking all terminology, notation and
definitions (or even the way some theorems are stated) for a God-given
immutable truth. Even here, on SE, students ask questions, not
realizing that we may not know their notations, or the definitions
they use in class. The magic of true names does not die easily.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to venture an opinion that is different from those of  @babou and @YuvalFilmus: It is **vital** for pure $\lambda$-calculus to have anonymous functions. The problem with having only named functions is that you need to know in advance how many names you will need. But in the pure $\lambda$-calculus you have no a priori bound on the number of functions used (think about recursion), so you either use (1) anonymous functions, or (2) you go the $\pi$-calculus route and provide a fresh name combinator ($\nu x.P$ in $\pi$-calculus) that gives an inexhaustible supply of fresh names at run-time.

The reason pure $\lambda$-calculus does not have an explicit mechanism for recursion is that pure $\lambda$-calculus was originally intended to be a foundation of mathematics by A. Church, and recursion makes such a foundation trivially unsound. So it came as a shock when  Stephen Kleene and J. B. Rosser discovered that pure $\lambda$-calculus is unsuitable as a foundation of mathematics ([Kleene–Rosser paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%E2%80%93Rosser_paradox)). Haskell Curry analysed the Kleene-Rosser paradox and realised that its essence is what we now know as Y-Combinator.

Added after @babou's comment: there is nothing wrong with having named functions. You can do this as follows:
$\mathsf{let} f = M \mathsf{in} N$
is a shorthand for
$
   (\lambda f.N)M
$
in the call-by-value $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: I think the OP wanted the ability to name functions, not to forbid
anonymous ones. This said, I would think that any requirement of
λ-calculus regarding the need for anonymous functions would show as
well in languages like Lisp/Scheme or ML. In the case of
Lisp/Scheme, the meta-circularity of evaluators should
make it possible to create new names as needed, though I am not sure
I would want it that way in a formal system. The use of unbounded
number of functions is not necessarily a problem when recursion allows
local reuse of already used names.

Comment: @babou Scheme and ML have letrec, so they can easily live with a finite number of named functions. I'd be interested to see a presentation of the pure $\lambda$-calculus with an explicit scheme for reusing names.  And yes, the ability to name functions (and other terms) is perfectly compatible with the pure $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: Should the last line read (lambda f. N) M?

Comment: @JoethePerson Yes, well spotted. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the idea is that names are not necessary.  Anything that appears to require names can be written as anonymous functions.

You can think of the lambda calculus like assembly language.  Someone in a lecture on assembly might say "There are no object oriented inheritance trees in assembly language." You might then think up a clever way to implement inheritance trees, but thats not the point.  The point is that inheritance trees are not required at the most basic level of how a physical computer is programed.

In the lambda calculus the point is that names are not required to describe an algorithm at the most basic level.

Answer (score 4):

I'm enjoying the 3 answers here so far -- most especially @babou's Shakespearen analysis -- but they don't shed light on what I think is the essence of the question.

λ-calculus does bind names to functions whenever you apply a function to a function. The issue is not the lack of names.

*"The problem is that a function cannot call itself simply" by referring to its name.*

(In pure Lisp, the name --> function binding is not in scope within the function's body. For a function to call itself by its name, the function would have to refer to an environment that refers to the function. Pure Lisp has no cyclic data structures. Impure Lisp does it by mutating the environment that the function refers to.)

As @MartinBerger pointed out, the historical reason that λ-calculus doesn't let a function call itself by name was an attempt to rule out [Curry's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%27s_paradox) when trying to use λ-calculus as a foundation of mathematics, including deductive logic. This didn't work since techniques like the Y combinator allow recursion even without self-reference.

From Wikipedia:

> If we can define function `r = (λ.x x x ⇒ y)` then `r r = (r r ⇒ y)`.
>
> If `r r` is true then `y` is true. If `r r` is false then `r r ⇒ y` is
>   true, which is a contradiction. So `y` is true and as `y` can be any
>   statement, any statement may be proved true.
>
> `r r` is a non-terminating computation. Considered as logic `r r` is
>   an expression for a value that does not exist.

Comment: I am pretty new to lambda calculus, so I had a question, which I have had for pretty much forever by now. What does $\lambda.x \space x x$ mean? I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean multiply $x$ by $x$. Does it mean apply the expression $x$ to itself? Also, what does the part => y signify?

Comment: @RohanPrabhu `λ.x x x` translates to Lisp as `(lambda (x) (x x))` and to JavaScript as `function (x) {return x(x);}`. `x⇒y` means `x implies y`, about the same as `(NOT x) OR y`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus

Comment: Thank you for answering that embarrassing rookie question!